# Javascript effiecient pattern print

Tags: javascript, performance, document.write

I want to print as given below:

```
5 5 5 5 5
 4 4 4 4
  3 3 3
   2 2
    1
   2 2
  3 3 3
 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
```

I was able to get to the top half of the pattern using 2 for loops.

```
print(5);

function print(n) {
    for(i=n;i>=1;i--) {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            console.log(i+" ");
        }
         console.log("<br>");   
    }
}
```

Please refer to  http://jsfiddle.net/5k8jLgmo/ for a live demo
Change the `console.log` to `document.write`

Question 1 - How to print the reflection? I can make use of another similar for loops. but is there a more efficient way?

Question 2 - To print the first half, i used 2 for loops. Can it be done with O(n)?

Question 3 - How can i `document.write` 'n' spaces.
Example if i had to print `"face   book"` (3 spaces between the words).
how to get it done?
basically its not a simple `document.write("face   book")` but the spaces keep changing based on say i-th value of the loop.

Comment: Question 3 seems to be unrelated... and what have you tried?

Comment: What is the code you use for creating the top half? SO is a place where we fix small problems for you, not some magical code writing machine

Comment: @nicael  - http://jsfiddle.net/5k8jLgmo/

Comment: @SZenC - Check the fiddle in above statemnt

Comment: aren't you supposed to just half it and do it in two go's ? n/2

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow about problems with code should include the code IN THE QUESTION. Please edit your question and edit in an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @kushalbhandari Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5k8jLgmo/1/) for a simpler approach that should get you going (isn't doing spaces at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with 1 JavaScript loop,
BUT the `Array()` constructor, `.join()` and `.reverse()` methods are internal loops, which means will usually run much faster.

**Version 1 to 9:**

```
function hourGlassString(n) {
    if (n<2) return '1';

    var r=[], out='', org=n, pad='';

    while (n>0) {
        pad=Array(org - n + 1).join(' ');
        r.push(pad + Array(n).join(n + ' ') + n + pad);
        n--;
    }

    out=r.join("\n");
    r.pop();
    out+="\n" + r.reverse().join("\n");

    return out;
}

console.log(hourGlassString(9));
```

Output:

```
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
  7 7 7 7 7 7 7  
   6 6 6 6 6 6   
    5 5 5 5 5    
     4 4 4 4     
      3 3 3      
       2 2       
        1        
       2 2       
      3 3 3      
     4 4 4 4     
    5 5 5 5 5    
   6 6 6 6 6 6   
  7 7 7 7 7 7 7  
 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

**Version up to 99:**

```
function hourGlassStringE(n) {
    if (n<2) return '1';

    var r=[], out='', org=n, pad='';

    while (n>0) {
        var s=' ';
        pad=Array(org - n + 1).join(s);
        if (n<10 && org>9) s=s + s;
        r.push(pad + Array(n).join(n + s) + n + pad);
        n--;
    }

    out=r.join("\n");
    r.pop();
    out+="\n" + r.reverse().join("\n");

    return out;
}

console.log(hourGlassStringE(13));
```

Output:

```
13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 
  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  
   10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10   
    9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9    
     8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8     
      7  7  7  7  7  7  7      
       6  6  6  6  6  6       
        5  5  5  5  5        
         4  4  4  4         
          3  3  3          
           2  2           
            1            
           2  2           
          3  3  3          
         4  4  4  4         
        5  5  5  5  5        
       6  6  6  6  6  6       
      7  7  7  7  7  7  7      
     8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8     
    9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9    
   10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10   
  11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  
 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 
13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13
```

Built with left + right padding;

To answer your 3rd question `html` collapses all the spaces into a single one. And to get around this you could use `&nbsp;` or `\u2000` ( ) or other whitespace. And `element.innerHTML` instead of `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

```
function print(n) {
    for(i=n;i>=1;i--) {
        for(j=i;j<=n;j++) document.write("&nbsp;");
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            document.write(i+" ");
        }
        document.write("<br>");   
    }
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++) {  // This needs to be n
        for(j=i;j<=n;j++) document.write("&nbsp;");
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
            document.write(i+" ");
        }
        document.write("<br>");   
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this generic? you are fixating `5` in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about efficiency per se, but certainly a cleaner method than loads of `for` loops (in my eyes):

```
function hourglassNum(n)
{
  var num,i,j=0,k=0,str=''; 
  for(i=1; i<(n*2) ; i++, str='', j=0, k=0)
  {
    num = Math.abs(i-n)+1;
    while(j++ < n - num) str += ' ';
    while(k++ < num) str += ' '+num;
    console.log(str);
  }
}
hourglassNum(5);
```

It involves looping through double the target number, and changing the printable number inside the loop by working out the loop index's difference from the target number in the middle: `Math.abs(i-n)`. We then add 1 to that to avoid the loop being 4 -> 0. Once that's done just do some simple while loops to add spaces and the printable number.

Update: turns out this actually is pretty good performance-wise. Currently outruns your existing incomplete code and the current other solution: [JSPerf test](http://jsperf.com/js-pattern-print)

Comment: Nice solution, but hey...the pattern is not complete without getting to that correct structure given in the OP.

Comment: Your solution runs faster. both of our solution is O(n2). is it because you are using a while loop?

Comment: @kushalbhandari The output looks right to me? Have you checked the console when you run it? While is indeed faster than a for loop in certain cases

Answer (score 0):

> How to print the reflection?

Just run your outer loop (the one over the lines) in reverse.

> I can make use of another similar for loops. but is there a more efficient way?

If you care about the code duplication, then use a function to abstract this - either one just for the inner loop, or one for the outer loop that is given the direction.

Of course you could store the first lines in an array, print it, `.reverse()` it and print it out again, but that would incur space inefficiency.

> To print the first half, i used 2 for loops. Can it be done with O(n)?

No, you cannot print n² characters in O(n). Two nested loops are perfectly fine, they use constant space and minimal time.

Comment: What does n2 characters mean?

Comment: @kushalbhandari: You're printing in a rectangular space with side lengths n, which gives a quadratic amount of letters to print.

Comment: I could not understand the terms "side lengths n" and "quadratic amounts". If you could tell it in details, sounds interesting :)

Comment: `n` is the largest number you are trying to print. For that triangle, you need to print `n` `n`s and `n-1` spaces, then `n-1` `n-1`s and spaces etc, which makes `O(n²)` characters combined.